# What is the difference between traditional JavaScript objects and objects created using "new" keyword?

Tags: javascript, oop

I need to know the differences between these `person1` and `person2`.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(Firstname, Lastname) {
    this.Firstname = Firstname;
    this.Lastname = Lastname;;
  }
  display() {
    console.log(this.Firstname + " " + this.Lastname);
  }
}


const person1 = new Person("George", "Clooney");

const person2 = {
  Firstname: "George",
  LastName: "Clooney"
}
```

Comment: OP is not using `new Object`

Comment: simple: the first line is not javascript while the following are just an object variable

Comment: @Mister Jojo The first line is JavaScript

Comment: No : I've this error : **ReferenceError: Person is not defined**

Comment: Nit: ‘new’ (and the related constructor and prototype chain) has been around since the inception of JavaScript, so it’s just as “traditional”. It is ‘class’, largely as a newer wrapper, which was introduced..

Answer (score 0):

The first is instantiating a `Person` class, whereas the second is making an object. However, you have not provided anything about this Person class.

Comment: person class has a constructor which initialize the FirstName and the LastName. And it also has a display method.

Comment: `class Person{
    constructor(Firstname,Lastname){
        this.Firstname=Firstname;
        this.Lastname=Lastname;;
    }
     display(){
        console.log(this.Firstname+" "+this.Lastname);
     }
}`